# web data having unequal length arrays python 3

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Below is my code to scrape a website. i have to create a DataFrame with arrays of unequal length, for instance property_Type has varying length, soe listings have one property_type , some has two & some has three. Similarly , Agency name also has varying length.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

urls = []

for i in range(1,3):
    pages = "http://www.realcommercial.com.au/for-sale/property-offices-retail-in-vic/list-{0}?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-date&autoSuggest=true".format(i)
    urls.append(pages)

Data = []

for info in urls:
    page = requests.get(info)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a', attrs ={'class' :'details-panel'})
    hrefs = [link['href'] for link in links]

    for href in hrefs:
        pages = requests.get(href)
        soup_2 =BeautifulSoup(pages.content, 'html.parser')
        Address_1 = soup_2.find_all('p', attrs={'class' :'full-address'})
        Address = [Address.text.strip() for Address in Address_1]
        Prop_Type = soup_2.find_all('div', attrs={'class' :'propType ellipsis'})
        Property_Type = [Property_Type.text.strip() for Property_Type in Prop_Type]
        Agency_1=soup_2.find_all('div', attrs={'class' :'agencyName ellipsis'})
        Agency_Name=[Agency_Name.text.strip() for Agency_Name in Agency_1]
        Agent_1=soup_2.find_all('div', attrs={'class' :'agentName ellipsis'})
        Agent_Name=[Agent_Name.text.strip() for Agent_Name in Agent_1]
        raw_data = dict(A=np.array(Address),B=np.array(Property_Type),C=np.array(Agency_Name),D=np.array(Agent_Name))
        raw_df = pd.DataFrame(dict([ k,series(v) for k,v in raw_data.iteritems() ]))
```

The error i am getting is

```
File "<ipython-input-8-3a7c5fc4fb93>", line 32
    raw_df = pd.DataFrame(dict([ k,series(v) for k,v in raw_data.iteritems() ]))
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What should i do to have a dataframe where only the relevant values fall under relevant columns, like property type should be in property type and not fall in agency name.

Any help would be highly appreciated,
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

`series` appears to do nothing -- perhaps you mean to turn each `v` into a pandas Series with `pd.Series`. Also, the syntax inside `dict([...])` appears to be way off. If you want to create key:value pairs where each value is a Series, and then to use the key:value pairs to create a DataFrame, you can do it with a dictionary comprehension, like so:

`raw_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k:pd.Series(v) for k,v in raw_data.iteritems()})`

Comment: With this code , i am getting the following error

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: `.iteritems()`, as included in your original code, is python 2. Your title mentions python 3. I believe you use `.items()` in python 3.

Comment: It is not working,,It is now producing NaN values for Property_Type,

Comment: NaN values are expected for arrays with a shorter length than the longest array in the DataFrame (which will then become the length of the DataFrame). Why don't you post an example of `raw_data` that isn't giving you the result you want?

Comment: The output i am getting is only the following record and not the entire data 
                A                                  B               C                                  D
0   1/36 Railway Place,            NaN       Miles Real Estate          Paul Evans
     Fairfield, VIC 3078                           - Ivanhoe & Rosanna    Tim Mitchell

Comment: I meant a minimal reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's nothing I can test from that. I would need an example of `raw_data` that I can use in my interpreter to test the `raw_df` assignment.

Comment: {'A': array(['1/36 Railway Place, Fairfield, Vic 3078'], 
       dtype='<U39'),
 'B': array([], dtype=float64),
 'C': array(['Miles Real Estate - Ivanhoe & Rosanna'], 
       dtype='<U37'),
 'D': array(['Paul Evans', 'Tim Mitchell'], 
       dtype='<U12')}

Comment: This is i am getting while printing raw_data

Comment: Can you not see that 'B' is an empty array? `'B': array([], dtype=float64)`. Your problem is somewhere in your existing code, not the answer I provided.

Comment: Data.append(Address+Property_Type+Agency_Name+Agent_Name)

Comment: SO is not a debugging forum. Please spend time debugging your own code and, if you have a specific question for which you cannot find an answer after searching online, then post another question, but only after reading how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The same code for property_type works completely fine if i use following line instead of last two rows( raw_data & raw_df lines) of my earlier code 

Data.append(Address+Property_Type+a+b+Agency_Name+c+d+Agent_Name)
The only issue with the above line is that the values are getting jumbled , like in case of property type having more than one word, they are falling in Agency_Name or Agent_Name, and cleaning the same in excel is a tedious job
hence i m looking for a work around here in code itself